# How to define an example in a JSP taglib <tag-file> element?

Tags: tomcat, jsp-tags

I'm currently writing a bunch of JSP tags for our designers to use. In my .tld file I have some `<tag>` and many more `<tag-file>` elements.

Now, I want to give the users of the tag library some examples about how to use them. According to [Sun's documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html) both `<tag-file>` and `<tag>` elements are allowed to have an `<example>` element.

This works fine for `<tag>`, but whenever I try to put an example in `<tag-file>` both Eclipse and Tomcat throw an error.

Anybody got experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<example>` element was introduced in Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0.

Apart from declaring the taglib root as JSP taglib 2.0 like follows

```
<taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
```

are you also using an appserver which is capable of Servlet 2.4 / JSP 2.0? For example Tomcat 5.x or newer. If not, then you need to upgrade. If so, then this question: is a proper Servlet version (at least 2.4) been declared in `web.xml`? If not, then ensure that you're doing so:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">
```

or, if you're already using a Servlet 2.5 capable appserver (for example Tomcat 6.x) then just declare Servlet 2.5 to be the best up to date:

```
<web-app 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">
```

If you don't want to upgrade the appserver or to change the Servlet API version declaration in `web.xml`, then you need to live with the fact that you cannot use the `<example>` element.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on Tomcat 6.0. Here is my file,

```
<tagtoc name="Configuration Components">
  <tag-file>
    <description>Get configured value</description>
    <display-name>get</display-name>
    <name>get</name>
    <path>/META-INF/tags/config/get.tag</path>
    <example>
       <![CDATA[
               <config:get key="username" echo="true" />
      ]]>
      <usage>
        <comment>
          <p>
            See config-test.jsp in the example application.
          </p>
        </comment>
      </usage>
    </example>
  </tag-file>
```

...